# simple z-buffer implementation example in JS? [beginner]

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm looking for a very basic implementation of the Z-buffer, ideally in JS. I am trying to take a look at a very simple code, for example two polygons overlapping, one hiding the other.
I can't find such basic example, while I can find a couple of "well-above my current level and understanding" samples.
Is there a resource you could recommend to get started?

Thank you for your help and recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Z-Buffer(also known as depth buffer) is nothing more than a 2D pixel array(think image). Instead of RGB it only stores a single value in each pixel, the distance from the current viewpoint:

```js
// one value for each pixel in our screen
const depthBuffer = new Array(screenWidth * screenHeight);
```

It augments the color buffer that contains the actual image you present to the user:

```js
// create buffer for color output
const numChannels = 3; // R G B
const colorBuffer = new Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * numChannels);
```

For every pixel of a shape you draw you check the Z-Buffer to see if there's anything closer to the camera that occludes the current pixel, if so you don't draw it. This way you can draw things in any order and they're still properly occluded on a per pixel level.

Z-Buffering may not only be used in 3D but also in 2D to achieve draw order-independence. Lets say we want to draw a few boxes, this will be our box class:

```js
class Box {
  /** @member {Object} position of the box storing x,y,z coordinates */
  position;
  /** @member {Object} size of the box storing width and height */
  size;
  /** @member {Object} color of the box given in RGB */
  color;

  constructor (props) {
    this.position = props.position;
    this.size = props.size;
    this.color = props.color;
  }

  /**
   * Check if given point is in box
   * @param {Number} px coordinate of the point
   * @param {Number} py coordinate of the point
   * @return {Boolean} point in box
   */
  pointInBox (px,py) {
    return this.position.x < px && this.position.x + this.size.width > px
        && this.position.y < py && this.position.y + this.size.height > py;
  }
}
```

With this class we can now create a few boxes and draw them:

```js
const boxes = [
  new Box({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50, z: 10 },
    size: { width: 50, height: 20 },
    color: { r: 255, g: 0, b:0 }
  }),
  // green box
  new Box({
    position: { x: 80, y: 30, z: 5 },
    size: { width: 10, height: 50 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 255, b:0 }
  }),
  // blue
  new Box({
    position: { x: 60, y: 55, z: 8 },
    size: { width: 50, height: 10 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  })
];
```

With our shapes specified we can now draw them:

```js
for(const box of boxes) {
  for(let x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
    for(let y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
      // check if our pixel is within the box
      if (box.pointInBox(x,y)) {
        // check if this pixel of our box is covered by something else
        // compare depth value in depthbuffer against box position
        // this is commonly referred to as "depth-test"
        if (depthBuffer[x + y * screenWidth] < box.position.z) {
          // something is already closer to the viewpoint than our current primitive, don't draw this pixel:
          continue;
        }
        // we passed the depth test, put our current depth value in the z-buffer
        depthBuffer[x + y * screenWidth] = box.position.z;
        // put the color in the color buffer, channel by channel
        colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 0] = box.color.r;
        colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 1] = box.color.g;
        colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 2] = box.color.b;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this code is exemplary so it's overly verbose and inefficient for the sake of laying out the concept.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("output").getContext('2d');
const screenWidth = 200;
const screenHeight = 200;

// one value for each pixel in our screen
const depthBuffer = new Array(screenWidth * screenHeight);

// create buffer for color output
const numChannels = 3; // R G B
const colorBuffer = new Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * numChannels);

/**
 * Represents a 2D box
 * @class
 */
class Box {
  /** @member {Object} position of the box storing x,y,z coordinates */
  position;
  /** @member {Object} size of the box storing width and height */
  size;
  /** @member {Object} color of the box given in RGB */
  color;

  constructor (props) {
    this.position = props.position;
    this.size = props.size;
    this.color = props.color;
  }

  /**
   * Check if given point is in box
   * @param {Number} px coordinate of the point
   * @param {Number} py coordinate of the point
   * @return {Boolean} point in box
   */
  pointInBox (px,py) {
    return this.position.x < px && this.position.x + this.size.width > px
        && this.position.y < py && this.position.y + this.size.height > py;
  }
}

const boxes = [
  // red box
  new Box({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50, z: 10 },
    size: { width: 150, height: 50 },
    color: { r: 255, g: 0, b:0 }
  }),
  // green box
  new Box({
    position: { x: 80, y: 30, z: 5 },
    size: { width: 10, height: 150 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 255, b:0 }
  }),
  // blue
  new Box({
    position: { x: 70, y: 70, z: 8 },
    size: { width: 50, height: 40 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  })
];
const varyZ = document.getElementById('varyz');
varyZ.onchange = draw;
function draw () {
  // clear depth buffer of previous frame
  depthBuffer.fill(10);
  for(const box of boxes) {
    for(let x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
      for(let y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
        // check if our pixel is within the box
        if (box.pointInBox(x,y)) {
          // check if this pixel of our box is covered by something else
          // compare depth value in depthbuffer against box position
          if (depthBuffer[x + y * screenWidth] < box.position.z) {
            // something is already closer to the viewpoint that our current primitive, don't draw this pixel:
            if (!varyZ.checked) continue;
            if (depthBuffer[x + y * screenWidth] < box.position.z + Math.sin((x+y))*Math.cos(x)*5) continue;
          }
          // we passed the depth test, put our current depth value in the z-buffer
          depthBuffer[x + y * screenWidth] = box.position.z;
          // put the color in the color buffer, channel by channel
          colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 0] = box.color.r;
          colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 1] = box.color.g;
          colorBuffer[(x + y * screenWidth)*numChannels + 2] = box.color.b;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // convert to rgba for presentation
  const oBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(screenWidth*screenHeight*4);
  for (let i=0,o=0; i < colorBuffer.length; i+=3,o+=4) {
  oBuffer[o]=colorBuffer[i];
  oBuffer[o+1]=colorBuffer[i+1];
  oBuffer[o+2]=colorBuffer[i+2];
  oBuffer[o+3]=255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(new ImageData(oBuffer, screenWidth, screenHeight),0,0);
}

document.getElementById('redz').oninput = e=>{boxes[0].position.z=parseInt(e.target.value,10);draw()};
document.getElementById('greenz').oninput = e=>{boxes[1].position.z=parseInt(e.target.value,10);draw()};
document.getElementById('bluez').oninput = e=>{boxes[2].position.z=parseInt(e.target.value,10);draw()};

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
margin-right: 2rem;
}
label {display:block;}
label span {
display:inline-block;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200" id="output"></canvas>
<label><span>Red Z</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="10" id="redz"/>
</label>
<label><span>Green Z</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="greenz"/>
</label>
<label><span>Blue Z</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="8" id="bluez"/>
</label>
<label><span>Vary Z Per Pixel</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="varyz"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was having issues running the code on my set up, crashing at "depthBuffer.fill(10);" as unrecognized. I'm starting to understand (I think) what you mean about inefficiencies. It is a great starting point, thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm that's weird, all current browsers should support `fill`, especially when they don't complain about `class` and `const` syntax.